# How to make vertical PagerTabStrip for VerticalViewPager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have a custom vertical view pager that extends view pager. now i want to include pagerTabStrip. Now the thing is it can be align either on top or bottom. But for this customized viewpager i need vertical pagertabstrip as the pages/fragments scrolls verticall.

Here is the code of VerticalViewPager

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // The majority of the magic happens here
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }

    private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                view.setAlpha(1);

                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

                //set Y position to swipe in from top
                float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
                view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
     */
    private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();

        float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
        float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

        ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

        return ev;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
        swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return intercepted;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    }

}
```

The Xml for the VewPager is

```
<com.mypackage.customViews.VerticalViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:scrollIndicators="top"

        >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding8"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding8"
            android:textColor="@color/link_color" />
    </com.TCYonline.android.BetterThink.customViews.VerticalViewPager>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: PagerTabStrip only lays out horizontally...  You need a custom tab implementation for vertical tabs.

Comment: ok can you provide me a link which shows how to customze pagertabstrup