# Vertical pagerTabStrip orientation in viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewpager, master-detail

This is possible duplicate of 
[How to make vertical PagerTabStrip for VerticalViewPager android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870278/how-to-make-vertical-pagertabstrip-for-verticalviewpager-android)

but I'm still curious how to achieve the same effect, only in horizontal way?
Maybe there are any libraries for that or somebody know how to customize PagerTabStrip?

It has no orientation attribute, so I can't make it work at first glance.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pagerTabStrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top">
        </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same effect and architecture, using `Master/Detail Fragments`, like the layout of Email apps that show the inbox on one list fragment on the left vertically, and show the details of that message on the right in another fragment.

You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial) to implement Master/Detail in Android using Fragments.

Since the Master is a fragment which hosts a listview or recyclerview, you have great control and customization on the layouts.

Comment: This is pretty simple to implement, thanks. But what I'm curious about is the indicator. You need to update the whole recyclerView in order to put the indicator in the right place.